# JavaScript Hoisting in Repl.it

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I put this code into repl.it expecting to get an undefined is not a function error.

```
foo();

var foo = function (){
    console.log("Hey foo");
};
```

Due to hoisting, I thought it would be interpreted as

```
var foo;
foo();

foo = function (){
    console.log("Hey foo");
};
```

Instead it logged "Hey foo" to the interactive interpreter.

Does hoisting only apply within the scope of a function or what's happening here?

When I wrapped the above code in a function, as below, the results were as expected, indeed `undefined is not a function`.

```
function fooTester = (){
    foo();
    var foo = function (){
        console.log("Hey foo");
    }
}
fooTester();
```

Just looking for some clarification on what's going on here. [image: repl.it image]

Comment: it tells me TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't accidentally define foo sometime above your experiment? I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: in repl.it it's telling you this? Hmm... maybe there's some sort of caching going on? I literally only have the first example typed into repl, it's not part of a larger program.

Comment: Probably you did execute it once, then when executing it a second time `foo` is already defined.